# Write lat/lon stored in one column as "POLYGON(())" into separate columns

Tags: r, dataframe, split, coordinates

I have a vector column in a dataframe `df$geom` storing coordinates that looks like this:

```
POLYGON ((565542.98375 2127263.4997410, 565538.48450 2127261.3187302, 565541.96658 2127254.1162, 565546.465835 2127256.297297, 565542.9837 2127263.49974102))
```

I don't know what package `POLYGON(())` is from. How can I just split this into two separate x/y columns?

Comment: Hi @hmnoidk. You are using the `sf` library. And you need to use the `st_coordinates()` function to do what you want. Hope this helps. Note that it would be easier to help you more concretely if you provided your `sf` object using `dput(df)`. Cheers.

Comment: It's just a normal data frame with the above character string in a geom field. I can't use sf to pull out the coords.

Comment: Would it be possible to put the result of `dput(head(df))` in your question to help you more efficiently?